# Custom component two way data-binding updates without emitting event

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am trying to implement two-way data binding (v-model) on a custom component.
I [read the docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html#Customizing-Component-v-model) and found this:

> the value of lovingVue will be passed to the checked prop. The lovingVue property will then be updated when <base-checkbox> emits a change event with a new value.

Notice the part where it says: `property will then be updated when <base-checkbox> emits a change event with a new value`

I have a parent component (HelloWorld.vue), which has a list of child components (Note.vue). Each of this note is draggable. The parent component has a list of child components represented as array of objects, for each element of this array, one instance of note.vue is created using `v-for` and bound to the array element using `v-model` like this:

```
 <template v-for="(note, index) in notes">
    <note v-model="note.value" :key="note.id" :ref="note.id"></note>
  </template>
```

and note.vue accepts the v-model like this:

```
export default {
  name: "Note",
  model: {
    prop: "note",
    event: "even-this-is-not-working"
  },
  props: {
    note: {
      type: Object,
      default: () => null
    }
  },
```

Whenever a note is dragged around the updates properties of `note` prop internally (but does not emit the updated note), but still the bound `note` in the parent component gets updated. (I have verified this with vue dev tools as well as by adding a watcher on the note in parent component).

Code Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/custom-v-model-binding-bz61o?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue
Try to add a `note` by clicking `Add Note` and drag it around, you will see that the watcher in parent is fired even when there is no event being emitted from `Note.vue`.

Am I understanding the concept wrong? or is there any problem with the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you pass around objects and in JS, objects are passed by reference. Content of prop `note` inside your `Note` component is the same object as `notes[x].value` by identity (same place in the memory) so updates to its properties in `Note` component must be observable in your `HelloWorld` parent component

`v-model` would be needed only if you would like to **replace** the object in `notes[x].value` by different object created inside the `Note` component...

```js
let user = { name: 'John' };

console.log(user.name);

let admin = user; // admin is just reference to existing object

admin.name = 'Pete';

console.log(user.name); // 'Pete', changes are seen from the "user" reference
```